# NSDecimalAdd() - what does that const thing mean for the parameter?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

Two things are strange with NSDecimalAdd(). First, when I search for examples, people seem to provide parameters by reference like NSDecimalAdd(&foobar, &foo, &bar, ....) and so on. The second strange thing is this **const**. Why's the parameter saying it wants a constant there? And why does this not apply for *result*?

```
NSCalculationError NSDecimalAdd (
   NSDecimal *result,
   const NSDecimal *leftOperand,
   const NSDecimal *rightOperand,
   NSRoundingMode roundingMode
);
```

Maybe someone can make the secret "public" here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const` means the API will not change the value of the parameter you are passing in there. `result`, however, is where the result of the routine will go, so it must change -- hence no `const`.

Comment: Thanks! Now I get it. So that's also the reason why it is a good idea to pass those NSDecimal things by reference, I mean, like NSDecimalAdd(&resultDecimal, foo, bar, ...)?

Comment: I also believe that the structs are passed in by reference as an optimization, so that you don't have the overhead of copying them into the function.